# Re-install natty on top of an existing set up - possible?

Tags: 11.04, re-installation, ubuntu-studio

I seem to have broken some critical library bindings on my Ubuntu Studio set up by "upgrading" (and the quotes here do indicate a note of sarcasm) from Meerkat to Natty beta. The release version didn't fix what was botched. So, essentially, I have no way to run any app requiring GLX. Even glxinfo dies with a segment violation. Unity shrugs and drops me into classic mode automatically now too.

It's been 3 weeks, and I haven't found any suitable answers anywhere that will allow me to use this system the way I need to use it. So, I'm left with a final option - reinstall the system and see if it will work. (If not, I'll drop back to 10.10 until the world catches up again).

Question: is it possible to re-load the system from an .iso without having to also reformat/repartition the drive?

Answer (score 1):

When performing an installation using the CD we have the choice to update an existing system rather than reformatting the whole drive:

[image: update]

This feature will not work properly in a multi-boot setting.

**In any case it is strongly recommended to update your data prior to upgrading**

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can upgrade over your existing 11.04 install to the latest iso without issue.

As Takkat states there is issues upgrading using the CD on a multi boot system.

I dual boot Win7 and Ubuntu on separate hard drives and found this out the hard way when I upgraded my 10.10 installation to 11.04 using the CD method and it broke all manner of packages upon reboot.

To overcome the problem I simply booted into the live CD, chose the 'Something else' option instead and installed again without formatting and everything worked fine.

If you follow this method you will be OK.

Comment: Good to hear you can do this on dual boot as well

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your input. As it turned out, I decided to fully upgrade to a 64 bit (rather than continue with the 32 bit) configuration. Since I was being fairly aggressive, I grabbed what I couldn't simply replace and off-loaded the data onto every piece of gear I had in the house and took the plunge.

In a way, this turns out to be a much better configuration since I now have a separate /home, 64bit Ubuntu Studio and 64 bit Vista - which gets me to where I wanted to be when I tried dual booting the first time :/

All the apps are back up and I still have a few more things to work out, but that's where the fun is, right?